# Windbg's "dt" equivalent in IDA?

Tags: ida, static-analysis, windbg

I wanted to ask whether there is a simple way to see an object's structure (like windbg's "dt" command equivalent)?

Assuming of course I have the pdb file.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import your structure to idb in the local types window (shift F1), then you can apply your imported structure on the data which is pointed by cursor (ALT-Q)